# REGEXP_MATCH to find video length in a campaign name (DATA STUDIO)

Tags: regex, looker-studio, re2

I'm trying to create a new custom filed that matches the video length in a campaign name. The software I'm using is Google Data Studio.

For instance the campaign name I'm trying to match is the following:

```
367358_Reputation|CorporateReputation|Video|Awareness|DAN|NEST|MLT|CORP|IT|NP|ACQ|InStreamVideo|V1|it|LCL|DNP|NA|30s|16:9|mp4|Video|Ambiente|
```

I want to match "30s" and the code I'm writing in Data Studio is the following:

```
CASE
  WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Campaign, "(.*30s.*)") THEN "Video length 30"
  ELSE NULL
END
```

Answer (score 1):

The `REGEXP_MATCH` function evaluates a field or expression using [Google RE2](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax) regular expression. Use the expression below

```
CASE WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Campaign, ".*30s.*") THEN "Video length 30" END
```

PS: You also have a typo in your word *REGEXP_MTACH* should be ***REGEXP_MATCH***

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply! but it doesn't work, I don't know why

Comment: oh thats sad, I just did a test with your string and it works in dataStudio, can you share your full custom field code?